# Ejecución de función dentro del evento SUCCESS de $.Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

espero me puedan aconsejar.

Con el evento `SUBMIT` del formulario `#NUEVO_PACIENTE`, utilizo `$.ajax` para enviar la información a la base de datos.  Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
 $('#nuevo_paciente').submit(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var datos = new FormData($('#nuevo_paciente')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: datos,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (respuesta){
                $('#primera_vez').modal('hide');  
                    abrir_agenda("agendaDay"); 
            }
        })
        abrir_agenda();
    })
```

El asunto es que la función ABRIR_AGENDA no se ejecuta.  Es una función que simplemente llama al plugin FULL CALENDAR dentro de un DIV del DOM.  Nada extraordinario.

Funciona muy bien cuando se abre la aplicación, pero cuando la llamo desde el evento `success`, simplemente no responde, y por lo tanto los eventos de `FULL CALENDAR` no se actualizan.

¿Alguien nota qué estoy haciendo mal?  GRACIAS!

Comment: Te saca algún error en consola ? has revisado ?

Comment: añádele una función para manejar el evento `error`. Luego de definir `success`, define `error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    console.log("Status: " + textStatus, "Error: " + errorThrown); 
                } `. Así podrás saber por qué no se ejecuta el contenido de `success`. El llamado a `abrir_agenda` luego del ajax está de más

Answer (score 2):

Las peticiones de este tipo se pueden ejecutar de dos formas

1. `sincrono` : espera respuesta de la petición antes de continuar con el código

   2.`asincrono` : continua ejecutando el código aun cuando el servidor no a respondido

para el caso de `$.AJAX` se puede definir el tipo de petición agregando el parametro `async` así:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: datos,
        async : false,    //de esta forma
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (respuesta){
            $('#primera_vez').modal('hide');  
                abrir_agenda("agendaDay"); 
        }
 })
```

se define `false` para que funcione `sincrono` y espere respuesta del servidor antes de continuar ejecutando, y se define como `true` cuando queremos que sea `asincrono`.

Teniendo esto en cuenta pruebe con definir como `async:false`, cambiando el orden y asignando un parámetro `error` en caso de que la petición falle, así:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: datos,
        async: false,     //que espere respuesta
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (respuesta){
            abrir_agenda("agendaDay");  //que sea lo primero que ejecute en caso de que la peticion sea exitosa
            $('#primera_vez').modal('hide');  
        },
        error : function(){
          //aquí lo que se ejecuta en caso de que falle
        }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado temporalmente con un

window.location.assign

De ese modo se carga la página y la función se ejecuta luego del evento DOCUMENT.READY, pero no me parece que sea lo mas correcto...

Answer (score 0):

Buenas espero esto sea lo que buscas

La idea es hacer una petición `GET` y ponerle el metodo `then` que en este caso es lo mismo que el `success` solo que es una promesa que solo se ejecuta al retornar nuestro `Ajax`

Espero te ayude.

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
$("#button").click(function(){


$.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  ejecutaEnSuccess(data);
});
})
function ejecutaEnSuccess(nuevoUsuario){
  //alert(JSON.stringify(nuevoUsuario))
  $("#textRetorno").text(JSON.stringify(nuevoUsuario))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textRetorno">
</div>
<button id="button" type="button" name="button">Ejecutar ajax</button>
```